# strtok in C crashes with char pointer

Tags: c, strtok

I have a char array in C with numbers separated by comma, and need to convert it to an int array. However when I try to use strtok, it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. 
Can you help me please?

**The method**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_LEN (0x100)
#define OUTPUT_LEN (0x400)

unsigned int StaticAnalyze_load( char* data, char delimiter, int* array, unsigned int length ){
    char *token;
    int i=0;

    // CRASHES HERE (BAD ACCESS)
    token = strtok(data, &delimiter);

    while( token != NULL ) {
        array[i] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, &delimiter);
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return length;
}
```

**Main**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
      char *data =  "13,654,24,48,1,79,14456,-13,654,13,46,465,0,65,16,54,1,67,4,6,74,165,"
           "4,-654,616,51,654,1,654,654,-61,654647,67,13,45,1,54,2,15,15,47,1,54";
      int array[ARRAY_LEN]; // array, I need to fill-in with integers from the string above
      unsigned int loaded = StaticAnalyze_load(data, ',', array, ARRAY_LEN);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&delimiter` is a pointer on char but not nul terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` in `main` is a pointer to a literal string that `strtok` cannot modify.
`strchr` could be used to identify the tokens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_LEN (0x100)
#define OUTPUT_LEN (0x400)

unsigned int StaticAnalyze_load( char* data, char delimiter, int* array, unsigned int length ){
    char *token = data;
    int i=0;

    while( i < ARRAY_LEN && token != NULL ) {
        array[i] = atoi(token);
        token = strchr(token, delimiter);
        if ( token) {
            ++token;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return length;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *data =  "13,654,24,48,1,79,14456,-13,654,13,46,465,0,65,16,54,1,67,4,6,74,165,"
       "4,-654,616,51,654,1,654,654,-61,654647,67,13,45,1,54,2,15,15,47,1,54";
    int array[ARRAY_LEN]; // array, I need to fill-in with integers from the string above
    unsigned int loaded = StaticAnalyze_load(data, ',', array, ARRAY_LEN);
    return 0;
}
```